# 2 Different Oracle DB Version on same server

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, installation, oracle-12c, rac

Is it possible to install and run 2 different oracle version(11g and 12c)software and db on same server?
is it possible then how we can? and if not then why?

Thanks

Rahul Joshi

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible.

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NTDBI/intro.htm#NTDBI2648

> Oracle Database supports multiple Oracle homes. You can install this
>   release or previous releases of the software more than once on the
>   same system, in different Oracle home directories. This allows
>   flexibility in deployment and maintenance of the database software.
>   **For example, it enables you to run different versions of the database**
>   **simultaneously on the same system**...

Answer (score 1):

It is possible.  However, review the following note from the Oracle documentation (https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NTDBI/intro.htm#NTDBI2648): 
Oracle Database supports multiple Oracle homes. You can install this release or previous releases of the software more than once on the same system, in different Oracle home directories. This allows flexibility in deployment and maintenance of the database software. For example, it enables you to run different versions of the database simultaneously on the same system, or it enables you to upgrade specific database instances on a system without affecting other running databases. ***However, when you have installed multiple Oracle homes on a single system, there is also some added complexity introduced that you must consider allowing these Oracle homes to coexist.***

Comment: What does your answer add to the existing one, posted five years ago?

Comment: I'm highlighting the fact there's added complexity.  That was mentioned in the previous answer, but was embedded in the documentation.